# Multicasting in android

Tags: android, multicast

We have enabled multicast streaming in one of our machines using VLC server. We use the following URL for streaming the multicast data.

rtp://239.1.2.11:5004 & udp://239.1.2.11:1234

But when we pass these links to the VideoView or mediaplayer in android, we get the message as "Sorry, the video can not be played".

Is it the case that multicast streaming is not supported in android? (Though multicastsocket class is present in library) or are we missing anything?

The links play well on the VLC client so we don't think there is any issue in VLC server.
We are using android v2.3 for development.

Comment: how are your videos encoded? what format are you using?

Comment: hi Ovidiu, The videos are encoded with H.264 format.

Comment: Thanks for the input Ovidiu. I tried using android supported media formats(Codec used was H.263 & H.264) but still no success. From the logs I found that the data source in mediaplayer/videoview is having issues. I got the error message as "PVMFErrNotSupported".

Comment: Can someone throw some light on the above query? We came to a conclusion that android default mediaplayer does not support multicasting. Is it correct? We are now thinking of using external media streaming library like mediastreamer2.

Comment: I don't think Android's MediaPlayer class can play RTP streams, it can only play RTSP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all an expert in video encoding, but I think the problem is not with the streaming, I think it is with the encoding of your videos. You should have a look at [Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) and make sure that your video encoding,format,resolution meet the recommendation specified there.

Comment: Thanks for the input Ovidiu. I tried using android supported media formats(Codec used was H.263 & H.264) but still no success.